# What is the svn equivalent of “git rev-list”? Or anyway to output svn log one line per commit?

Tags: svn, version-control

With `git rev-list id1..id2` I can get a list of the commit ids between id1 and id2.

However, in SVN, I can't find such a command -- `svn log` takes a lot of lines for each commit, and I can't get it just to output the revision number list.

Also, you can output `git log` in one line with formatting parameters; however, I only found `svn log -q` which reduces the log to two lines per commit.

Is there anyway to make svn output the data in the format that I want?

Ps. I am using Subversion 1.7.5 in linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a reduced output of `svn log -q`, you can filter the output with another command. If you need this reduced output frequently, you can add a function definition to your `.bashrc` and use this function instead of `svn log -q`.

I think the following function will work for you. You can use it with `svn-log -r 42:7`:

```
function svn-log() {
    svn log -q "$@" |
    sed -ne 's/^\(r[0-9]*\).*$/\1/p'
}
```